# How to scale font to fit in a specified rectangle

Tags: c#, math, graphics, gdi+

I want to draw a string in specified rectangle but problem is that the string with specified font may be outside the bound of rectangle.

So I want a way to scale string font to fit string in specified rectangle area.

```
public Font scaleFont(String text, RectangleF rect, Graphics graphics, Font pFont)
        {
            float fontSize = 20.0f;
            Font font = pFont;
            float width = graphics.MeasureString(text, pFont).Width;
            float height = graphics.MeasureString(text, pFont).Height;
            fontSize = ((rect.Width / width)  * pFont.Size);
            float heig = (rect.Height / height);
            return new Font(pFont.FontFamily, fontSize);
        }
```

The above code give me scaled font to fit the string in the top area of rectangle but I want to fit in whole area(Attaching out put of above algo)

[image: Output of algo]

But I want the following output.

[image]

Comment: In other words, you want the words to be wrapped by the box. Did I understand you right?

Comment: @AndreyAtapin,I have updated the question.

Comment: why are you doing `Font font = pFont` and then never using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By fitting in whole area you means that?

[image]

If so, the common way is drawing a text on a bitmap and fitting one to any object you want.

To avoid pixelization, you can use your piece of code to detect best font size and best bitmap size.

Comment: I think that you are right on target here.  I am working on a project where I had to do this kind of thing and that was the best idea I came up with as well.  I used this article as a guide line and it worked well for me. Credit to Michael Kuehl - here is the link [csharp-font-scaling](http://tech.pro/tutorial/691/csharp-tutorial-font-scaling)